# How are database schema and table schema related

Tags: schema, ssms

Sorry for this basic question.

As far as I understand, database schema as in Microsoft SQL is something like a  folder that adds a layer to separate the tables and to define security and access.

Table schema seems to be used as how the columns are defined, column name, type, constraints etc.

They don't seem to be the same thing. Since they both are called schema, are they in fact related?

Answer (score 0):

Columns belong to tables and tables belong to database schemas. Is simple.